# Minimizing the sum of squared residuals

Tags: regression-analysis, linear-regression

I have the equation 
$y=X\beta+u$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \ \times \ 1}$ , $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \  \times  (k+1)} $  ,  $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{(k+1)  \times \ 1 }$, and $u$ is the error term, and is a ${(k+1) \ \times \ 1 }$ matrix.

$$-2(y-X\beta)X=0\Leftrightarrow X'(y-X\beta)=0$$

Is there someone who can explain why the statement above is equivalent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

Check the dimensions for the first term $(y- X\beta) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ but $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (k+1)}$, the are not equivalent.

I think you intend to ask

$$-2(y-X\beta)'X=0 \iff X'(y-X\beta)=0 $$

This can be seen by taking transpose. recall that $(AB)'=B'A'$

Comment: So I have from a book of mine that if divide $-2(y-X\beta)X$ with -2 and take its transposed I get $X'(y-X\beta)$.

Comment: I think there is a typo then, or the matrix dimension doesn't match right?